# Errors in apache cordova android project

Tags: android, apache, cordova

I have a Problem with a Cordova project which I created like this:

1. `cordova platform add android`
2. `cordova build`
3. Then I made it like in the [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)

I also cleaned the project. But in the end I have this errors:
[image]

**How to solve them?**

Comment: Can you update Cordova and try again? And also make sure you have a config.xml file in res/xml/config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add the cordova.jar file into my libs folder.

strange that this is not described in the official documentation.